# Unable to get a proper UV Mapped object from Blender to Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

I have a UV Mapped Cereal box that I exported as an FBX file and its corresponding texture from Blender.

[image]

I imported these files into Unity and I'm noticing that the model is displayed as expected in the preview but when I drag and drop it into the scene view some part of the texture disappears (as can be seen in the snapshot below)

[image]

Any ideas on how this can be fixed?

Thank you.

In unity, I've also tried extracting the material and applying the texture asset from Blender to the extracted material in Unity but the problem still persists

[image]

Comment: Can you share the fbx file?

Comment: Please find the FBX and the Texture files here:
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/f3ed98c9b666ee069b18ddbab0f75b0820230526100940/972fef

Comment: The Blender file at https://wetransfer.com/downloads/fdb4c58fed4e6a9e47080fc684c544a020230526103147/15fb44. Version of Blender I used is 2.82

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no issue with the model, UV or FBX file in of itself. The problem is that you have exported a light source with it.

Blender and Unity have a very different understanding of what the intensity of the light actually means. In Blender it is in watts and in Unity its whatever the engineers decided normal daylight to be (there is no value given, but it is significantly more than 1 watt).

[image: gif comparing light intensity 1000 and 1]

As a result when you intended to light the box with the equivalent of 10 light bulbs you instead lit it with the power of 1000 suns. Obviously your display can't get bright enough to burn your retinas and has to settle for pure white.

You have a number of choices on how to fix this:

- manually change the intensity, like shown in the gif
- exclude light sources from export (in the Blender export settings you can do that under the `Include` tab `Object Types`)
- manually reduce the power of the light source in blender